# SwiftUI - Layout multiple Text views with tap gestures such that they overflow to the next line?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am receiving a body of text from an API in the form of a list of a strings (each representing a sentence) I would like to create a Text view for each sentence that looks something like this:

```
Text(str)
    .onTapGesture {
        print("Tap \(str)")
    }
    .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5) {
        print("Long Press \(str)")
    }
```

I need the gestures for various reasons.

Additionally I would like to layout these Texts as a paragraph such that when any text reaches the end of the container it wraps to the next line (if possible nicely by space delineation onto the next line).

In the following [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqHHO.png) I would like that the red box starts on the same line as the green box and then overflows

I tried:

- Creating a custom layout such that I can contain multiple views (In my case text views) and if they hit the end of the line they will be moved to the next line. (The example image above shows the result of this effort)

```
func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {        
        let layoutInfo = GetLayoutInfo(from: subviews, and: bounds.width)
        
        var x = bounds.minX
        var y = bounds.minY + layoutInfo.maxHeightWithSpacing
        
        for (index, sub) in subviews.enumerated()
        {
            let curLen = sub.sizeThatFits(.unspecified).width
            
            if (x + curLen + layoutInfo.spacingX[index] > bounds.width + bounds.minX)
            {
                x = bounds.minX
                y += layoutInfo.maxHeightWithSpacing
                
            }
            
            var loc = CGPoint()
            loc.x = x
            loc.y = y
            
            let proposedHeight = layoutInfo.maxHeightWithSpacing
            
            sub.place(at: loc, anchor: .bottomLeading, proposal: ProposedViewSize(width: min(curLen, bounds.width), height: proposedHeight ))

            x += curLen + layoutInfo.spacingX[index]
        }
    }
```

- Creating a custom layout where I allow the Text view to overflow when it hits the end of a line but I give it a proposed height of multiple lines. In this case it just overflows to the next line but with the bounding box starting at the same start point (which makes sense because in its Place method I give it an X value for the start). This resulted in [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zH6L.png)

```
func placeSubviews2(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        let layoutInfo = GetLayoutInfo(from: subviews, and: bounds.width)
        
        var x = bounds.minX
        var y = bounds.minY + layoutInfo.maxHeightWithSpacing
        
        for (index, sub) in subviews.enumerated()
        {
            let curLen = sub.sizeThatFits(.unspecified).width
            var overflows = false
            var overflowAmountX = CGFloat.zero
            var overflowLines = CGFloat.zero
            
            let lineLength = bounds.width + bounds.minX
            let potentialNewXPos = x + curLen + layoutInfo.spacingX[index]
            
            if (potentialNewXPos > lineLength)
            {
                overflows = true
                overflowAmountX = potentialNewXPos - lineLength
                overflowLines = ceil(overflowAmountX / lineLength)
            }
            
            var loc = CGPoint()
            loc.x = x
            loc.y = y
            
            let proposedHeight = layoutInfo.maxHeightWithSpacing * (overflowLines + 1)
            
            sub.place(at: loc, anchor: .bottomLeading, proposal: ProposedViewSize(width: lineLength - x, height: proposedHeight))
            
            
            if (overflows){
                x = bounds.minX + (overflowAmountX.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: (bounds.width + bounds.minX)))
                y += overflowLines * layoutInfo.maxHeightWithSpacing
            }
            else {
                x += curLen + layoutInfo.spacingX[index]
            }
        }
    }
```